# How can I connect 8 PS4 controllers to my PC Bluetooth?

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth, connection, ps4

Currently have windows 10 and using a gigabyte aorus motherboard which has built-in bluetooth.
Right now I am able to connect 3 controllers at max. If somebody has a PS4 controller and has connected to his PC via bluetooth then that person should know what I am saying.

Anyway I,ll try to explain my problem here. So here is what I do:
1)- Type bluetooth in search.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvu75.png)

2)- Click on the add bluetooth device button.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfpIT.png)

3)- Add then add the bluetooth device by clicking here.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5cB8.png)

4)- After that we press the playstation + share button and the controller shows up in the list.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o39DY.jpg)

Once the controller is connected the light on the ps4 controller stops blinking and is stable. Which means that the controller is now connected.

But right now I am able to connect only 3 controllers at the same time. The fourth controller's light just keeps on blinking. It looks like there is some bluetooth setting which is not allowing the fourth controller to get connected.

How can we fix this ?

Comment: You may need better drivers, or a different/better Bluetooth transceiver entirely but 7 sounds like it is a hard limit due to the way Bluetooth works. Likely there is some complicated stuff at the radio that makes 3 or 4 the practical limit.

Comment: @Mokubai
I have no problem in connecting 3 controllers. But more than 3 it becomes a problem. It takes some time for the 4th controller to get connected. Also the fourth controller gets disconnected sometimes during the game. Not sure why is that. But with only 3 controllers everything works perfectly. 

Anyway let me know if there is a fix for it.
What if I attach another Bluetooth device to my pc ? Will that work ?

Answer (score 1):

The answers so far are not correct. Bluetooth can indeed support more than 7 concurrent devices but it is totally dependent on the stack used. For example, the Nintendo Switch supports up to 8 concurrent controllers and some stacks support even up to 128 (link: https://www.reddit.com/r/NintendoSwitch/comments/6j0z2h/how_does_the_switch_support_8_controllers_when/djaslgc/ )! The issue is the current Windows stack maxes out at just seven devices. It isn’t a total show stopper since games max out at eight leaving you just one short of ideal, but those are the limits currently in place. One workaround for Windows users which requires additional investment is purchasing the Xbox Wireless Adapter (which uses Microsoft’s proprietary Wi-Fi Direct connection) and allows up to 8 Xbox wireless controllers via this wireless connection.